# Чтение казахских символов из файла

Tags: python, файлы

Проблема в том, что питон не хочет читать и выводить файл с таким содержанием:

1. Өлкетану қандай ғылым?

А) Белгілі бір өлке туралы білімдер жиынтығы

B) Ғылыми пәндердің обьектісі

C) Белгілі бір өлкенің өндіргіш күштері мен қоғамдық құрылысы

D) Белгілі бір өлкенің табиғат байлығы

E) Ғылыми зерттеулердің жиынтығы

2. Алғашқы кездері өлкетану ретінде нені түсінген?

А) Өлкенің табиғат жағдайларын зерттеуді

B) Белгілі бір өлке туралы білімдер жиынтығын

C) Белгілі бір өлкенің қоғамдық құрылысын

D) Белгілі бір өлкенің өндіргіш күштерін

E) Ғылыми зерттеулердің жиынтығын

Он просто выводит кучу непонятных символов, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно задана кодировка при открытии файла. По умолчанию **ANSI**. Вам нужна **UTF-8**.
Python3:

```py
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf=8") as file:
    #
```

Python2:

```py
import io

with io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf=8") as file:
    #
```